# Google Maps Library Codeigniter Problems

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

I've been doing some project by using google maps and codeigniter
I tried the google maps library for codeigniter
I'm trying to draw polyline from latitude and longitude stored in my database
when using marker it done perfectly but when I use the polyline the drawing was uncontrollable, can anyone gimme some pointer please?

here's the code I've been using
controller:

```html
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Map extends CI_Controller {
 function __construct()
 {
 parent::__construct();
 }
 function index()
 {
 // Load the library
 $this->load->library('googlemaps');
 // Load our model
 $this->load->model('map_model', '', TRUE);
 // Initialize the map, passing through any parameters
 $config['center'] = '7,112';
 $config['zoom'] = "auto";
 $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
 // Get the co-ordinates from the database using our model
 $coords = $this->map_model->get_coordinates();
 $x=0;
 // Loop through the coordinates we obtained above and add them to the map
 foreach ($coords as $coordinate) 
 {
  $x++;
  if($x%2==1)
  {
   $elat=$coordinate->lat;
   $elong=$coordinate->long;
   /*print $elat;
   print $elong;*/
   print '<br>';
   
  }
  if($x%2==0)
  {
   $lat=$coordinate->lat;
   $long=$coordinate->long;
   /*print $lat;
   print $long;*/
   print '<br>';
   
  }
  if($x>1&&$x<6)
  {

   if($x%2==0)
   {
    
     $polyline=array();
     $polyline['points']=array('$elat,$elong','$lat,$long');
     $this->googlemaps->add_polyline($polyline);
     print $x;
     print '<br>';
     print "(";
     print $elat;
     print $elong;
     print '<br>';
     print $lat;
     print $long;
     print ")";
    

   }
   if($x%2==1)
    {
     $polyline=array();
     $polyline['points']=array('$lat,$long','$elat,$elong');
     $this->googlemaps->add_polyline($polyline);
     print $x;
     print '<br>';
     print "(";
     print $elat;
     print $elong;
     print '<br>';
     print $lat;
     print $long;
     print ")";
    }
  }
  
 $marker = array();
 $marker['position'] = $coordinate->lat.','.$coordinate->long;
 $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
 
 }

 /*foreach ($coords as $coordinate) 
 {
 $marker = array();
 $marker['position'] = $coordinate->lat.','.$coordinate->long;
 $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
 $polyline=array();
 $polyline['points']=array($coordinate->lat,$coordinate->long.',');
 $this->googlemaps->add_polyline($polyline);
 }*/
 // Create the map
 $data = array();
 $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
 // Load our view, passing through the map data
 $this->load->view('map_view', $data);
 }
}
```

view :

```html
<html>
<head><?php echo $map['js']; ?></head>
<body><?php echo $map['html']; ?></body>
</html>
```

Model :

```html
<?php
class Map_model extends CI_Model {
 function __construct()
 {
 parent::__construct();
 }
 function get_coordinates()
 {
 $return = array();
 $this->db->select("lat,long");
 $this->db->from("track");
 $query = $this->db->get();
 if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
 foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
 array_push($return, $row);
 }
 }
 return $return;
 }
}
```

Comment: Here's what I noticed. Your $elat, $elong, $lat, $long are all declared inside the for each loop. Try declaring them before the loop with default value 0, like your $x.

Comment: Thanks so_jin_ee, but no luck bro, still the same